# Problem using gsl::span with a dynamic list of CStringArray objects is causing a abort

Tags: arrays, visual-c++, mfc, gsl

See this code:

```
if (pAryStrCustom != nullptr)
{
    const gsl::span spanAryStrCustom(pAryStrCustom, pAryStrCustom->GetSize());
    uStartIndex = FILLED_COLUMN_INDEX_MIKE +
        rsRowData.uNumMikesToFill + rsRowData.uNumAttendToFill;
    for (uAssign = 0; uAssign < rsRowData.uNumCustomToFill; uAssign++, uStartIndex++)
    {
        if (!IsReadOnly(rsRowData.uGridRow, rsRowData.aryUICustomColIndex[uAssign]))
        {
            // Only auto assign custom cells that are COMBO (ie: NOT read only)
            //if (!AutoAssign(1, uStartIndex, spanAryStrCustom[uAssign],
            //  rsRowData, rsRowData.aryUICustomColIndex[uAssign]))
            if (!AutoAssign(1, uStartIndex, pAryStrCustom[uAssign],
                rsRowData, rsRowData.aryUICustomColIndex[uAssign]))
            {
                bOK = FALSE;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Blank out name
            rsRowData.pAryStrNamesThisRow->SetAt(uStartIndex, _T(""));
        }
    }
}
```

This is how the main variable (`pAryStrCustom`) is defined:

```
CStringArray* CCreateReportDlg::BuildCustomAssignArray(const ROW_DATA_S &rsRowData)
{
    CStringArray    *pAryStrCustom = nullptr;

    if (rsRowData.uNumCustomToFill > 0)
    {
        pAryStrCustom =std::make_unique<CStringArray[]>(rsRowData.uNumCustomToFill).release();
        ASSERT(pAryStrCustom != nullptr);
        if (pAryStrCustom == nullptr)
            return nullptr;

        const gsl::span spanAryStrCustom(pAryStrCustom, rsRowData.uNumCustomToFill);

        const auto iNumAssigns = m_aryPtrAssign.GetSize();
        for (INT_PTR iAssign = 0, iUsedAssign = 0; iAssign < iNumAssigns; iAssign++)
        {
            const CUSTOM_ASSIGN_S* psAssign = static_cast<CUSTOM_ASSIGN_S*>(m_aryPtrAssign.GetAt(iAssign));
            if (psAssign != nullptr)
            {
                if (!psAssign->bExcluded && iUsedAssign < gsl::narrow<INT_PTR>(rsRowData.uNumCustomToFill))
                {
                    spanAryStrCustom[iUsedAssign].Copy(psAssign->aryStrBrothersAll);
                    iUsedAssign++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return pAryStrCustom;
}
```

I have debugged my code and I have an array of 5 `CStringArrays`. And each of the arrays do have content. But notice I had to comment out some code:

```
//if (!AutoAssign(1, uStartIndex, spanAryStrCustom[uAssign],
//  rsRowData, rsRowData.aryUICustomColIndex[uAssign]))
```

It dies if I use that `spanAryStrCustom` span. Why? Using a legacy array approach to access the data is fine.

This is the offending bit:

```
spanAryStrCustom[uAssign]
```

Comment: OT: I'd drop `CStringArray` alltogether and replace it with `std::vector<CString>`.

Comment: @jab I know. But there is a lot of code to refactor elsewhere if I make that change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the way I defined the span:

```
const gsl::span spanAryStrCustom(pAryStrCustom, rsRowData.uNumCustomToFill);
```

It was a mistake to use `pAryStrCustom->GetSize()` because it is actually an **dynamic** *array of* `CStringArray` objects. I now realise that using `GetSize()` was returning the size of the first array (`4`) which was actually making it one smaller than it needed to be (`5`).

So using the same `UINT` that was used to build the dynamic array was the answer.